# MongoDB find query

Tags: java, mongodb, find

I use mongoDB to collect comments inside a collection comments

I use this java programme to create them

> ```
> ...
> BasicDBObject comment=new BasicDBObject();
> BasicDBObject auteur=new BasicDBObject();
> auteur.put("id", id);
> auteur.put("login", login);
> auteur.put("contact",false);
> comment.put("auteur",auteur);
> comment.put("texte",texte);
> ...
> ```

When i try to find the comment using the field texte it works:

> db.comments.find({"texte":"my name is user1"})

```
{ 
 "_id" : ObjectId("5341395ae4b082f5895d5967"), 
"auteur" : { "id" : 1, "login" : "user1", "contact" : false },
"texte" : "my name is user1"
}
```

However my aim is to find them by using the the field id of auteur.
I tried

> db.comments.find({"auteur":{"id":1}})

but it returns nothing...

I'm really lost. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use the [Dot Notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) to access the `id` of the sub document `auteur`:

```
db.comments.find({"auteur.id": 1});
```

The dot notation can also be used to access an element of an array by the zero-based index position:

```
db.things.find({"an_array_name.15": "a text to search..."});
```

Regards.

Mohamed.